# Are "weather sealed" gear tested or rated for their sealing?

Tags: equipment-protection, weather, weather-sealing, testing

## Context

So I've been looking around at camera bodies and gear and noticed the more expensive ones have "weather sealing". From posts like [these](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41432/), I understand how it is implemented. However unlike [waterproof cameras](http://www.dpreview.com/articles/3864522077/), I haven't seen DSLR/mirrorless camera bodies with IP codes or have an standards of such with any code (exception of smaller point and shoots?)

From this I can conclude they are defined per manufacturer and since they don't have any "standards" I can assume they *may* survive better but it doesn't mean they will. Since they don't have IP codes, I assume cameras going into water is bad, goes without saying I suppose. Given how *vague* they are, I don't know how beneficial it is?

## Question

Are "weather sealed" gear tested for how good their "weather sealing" is?  Or is it more of the mentality of the, "every little bit helps" even if it's not a huge or noticeable amount?

## Reference

- [How to Ruin Your (or Our) Gear in 5 Minutes (Without Water)](http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2013/05/how-to-ruin-your-gear-in-5-minutes-without-water/)
- [How effective are the rear weather sealing rings on lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/54034)

Comment: I would say the weather sealing is good enough that manufacturers warrant sealed gear during the warranty period. To me, that seems a non-trivial financial risk if the seals don't work. I've shot with my cheap Pentax K50 kit in moderate rain enough to trust the seals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are "weather sealed" gear tested for how good their "weather sealing" is?

AFAIK, cameras aren't tested and rated against some independent standard -- if they were, manufacturers would certainly advertise that fact. Equipment is usually described as being weather sealed if it is, and weather sealing just isn't mentioned if it's not. Equipment reviews typically make an attempt to describe the degree and/or locations of weather sealing, [for example](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/upgrading-a-classic-canon-100-400mm-f4-5-5-6l-is-usm-mark-ii-review/3):

> The high build quality is very much to the normal Canon L-grade
>   standard, or even a touch above it with magnesium alloy for the outer
>   barrel (the extending front section is engineering-grade plastic) and
>   now with a full complement of weather-resistant seals.

There's a general understanding that *weather sealed* doesn't mean *waterproof* or even *water resistant*. If you're out in rain, snow, or dust with your weather sealed camera and lens, your camera will probably survive just fine. If you drop your camera in a pond, not so much.

> Given how vague they are, I don't know how beneficial it is?

Think of it like the airbags in your car: you don't know *exactly* how much they'll protect you, but it's still good to know that they're there.

Let common sense apply -- if you get caught in the rain with an unsealed camera, you should probably tuck it inside your jacket and find some shelter. If you get caught in the rain with a sealed camera, it's fine to keep shooting, but you don't necessarily want to expose it to a torrential downpour with driving wind.